# Only 2 out of 3 packets being sent using Async socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, packet

So I'm building a small client<->server communication application based on AsynchronousSocketChannel class.
I managed to get everything working: server runs, client is able to connect, packets are being sent/received all good.
That is at least until I try to send a bunch of packets one after another (lets say 3 packets), at first I run toward a WritePendingException which I was able to fix after searching around a little, but packets are still not being sent properly.
From my debug it seems like server tries to send 3 packets, it succesfully sends all 3, but client receives only the first 2, I cannot seem to understand where is the problem and there are no errors at all on console, if further debug required to help me just ask:

When creating packets, they are being added to _sendQueue like so:

```
_sendQueue.add(packet);
```

_sendQueue is a ConcurrentLinkedQueue of ByteBuffers (which are my packets).
Then packets are being sent by the following method:

```
public final void executeWriteTask()
{
    if (!_sendQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        _writeLock.lock();
        if (!_pendingWrite)
        {
            _pendingWrite = true;

            ThreadPool.execute(() ->
            {
                final PacketWriter packet = _sendQueue.poll();
                final ByteBuffer duplicate = packet.getBuffer().duplicate();
                System.out.println("Sending packet opcode: " + duplicate.getInt());
                _channel.write(packet.getBuffer(), this, _writeHandler);
            });
        }
        _writeLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

After every packet written, the method is being called again for the next packet in the queue, so basically all 3 are being sent, this is what my println shows:

```
Sending packet opcode: 0
Sending packet opcode: 1
Sending packet opcode: 1
```

Which is fine, but on client:

```
Received packet opcode: 0
Received packet opcode: 1
```

I tried many things, like trying to call read again manually after 3 seconds but there was no packet pending to be received, also I tried to send the 3rd packet from the server after 3 seconds and it worked, but that's not what I want, it was just to check if the problem indeed comes from the fact that I try to send the 3 packets instantly and I found out that it is.
So where did the 3rd packet go?? I cannot think of anymore ways to debug it deeper... any help would be appreciated.

Note I do want to build it on my own, so don't suggest me any pre-made communication codes.

Comment: Packets are lost on networks all the time, e.g. buffers, which are typically very, very small, can fill then the packets get dropped. That's why TCP was created to give reliable communications.

Comment: Sorry but i'm pretty sure my communication is based on TCP, since its based on java's AsynchronousSocketChannel

Comment: TCP will guarantee segment delivery, and it requests missing segments to be resent. You will get everything with TCP.

Comment: But its TCP, maybe the problem is not a packet being dropped like you said (but im not sure), I even got these options on: _channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
   _channel.setOption(StandardSocketOptions.TCP_NODELAY, true);

Comment: Are you opening a TCP session and using that same session for the whole thing, or are you opening and closing TCP sessions?

Comment: Using the same session.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it still doesnt answer my question directly, but it seem to solve the issue.
I guess there's some mechanism that prevents packet flood or so, so I decided that instead of sending packets one after another, they are being batched to 1 packet and then being sent as a whole, like so:

```
public final void executeWriteTask()
{
    if (!_sendQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        _writeLock.lock();
        if (!_pendingWrite)
        {
            _pendingWrite = true;

            ThreadPool.execute(() ->
            {
                final Queue<PacketWriter> copy = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
                while (!_sendQueue.isEmpty())
                    copy.add(_sendQueue.poll());

                int bytes = 0;
                for (final PacketWriter packet : copy)
                    bytes += packet.getBuffer().limit();
                final ByteBuffer toSend = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(bytes);
                for (final PacketWriter packet : copy)
                    toSend.put(packet.getBuffer());
                toSend.flip();

                _channel.write(toSend, this, _writeHandler);
            });
        }
        _writeLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Then in client:

```
@Override
public void readPacket()
{
    final ByteBuffer buffer = getReader().getBuffer();
    buffer.flip();

    while (buffer.hasRemaining())
    {
        final int opCode = getReader().readInt();
        final PacketInfo inf = PacketInfo.values()[opCode];
        final IIncomingPacket<GameClient> packet = inf.newIncomingPacket();
        packet.read(this, getReader());

        if (inf.isAuthedState() == isAuthed())
            packet.run(this);
    }
    buffer.clear();

    getChannel().read(buffer, this, getReadHandler());
}
```